# Spots progress dialog does not show animation

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm usign this library from https://github.com/d-max/spots-dialog and i don't know why but only the title is shown while the moving dots are not displayed.

Here is the code, is very simple

```
AlertDialog dialog = new SpotsDialog(this,"Searching..");
dialog.setCancelable(false);
dialog.show();
```

Any idea why this happens? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have forgot to add the custom style resource to the constructor (SpotDialog). This resource file defines the color of the spots.

Answer (score 0):

add this into your `style.xml`

```
<style name="Custom" parent="android:Theme.DeviceDefault.Dialog">
        <item name="DialogTitleAppearance">@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium</item>
        <item name="DialogTitleText">Updating…</item>
        <item name="DialogSpotColor">@android:color/holo_orange_dark</item>
        <item name="DialogSpotCount">4</item>
</style>
```

and then initialize the dialog like this

```
AlertDialog dialog = new SpotsDialog(this, R.style.Custom);
```

Comment: I've already tried but nothing change. I've also downloaded the demo by the developer and same result. I think it's a problem with the animation or something like that.